# Turn off Android Monitor Realm logs

Tags: android, realm

How can I turn off this never-ending stream of Realm logs? The huge amount of them makes using Android Monitor sad.

[image: example]

Comment: Have you tried disabling it with setting `RealmLog.setLevel()`?

Comment: When I try that, I get exception - No implementation found for void io.realm.log.RealmLog.nativeSetLogLevel(int) (tried Java_io_realm_log_RealmLog_nativeSetLogLevel and Java_io_realm_log_RealmLog_nativeSetLogLevel__I)

Comment: What is your Realm version? Do you by chance have any other Realm version accidentally added to the project? Also, do you still get the same issue after a clean + rebuild? (maybe even `gradlew --refresh-dependencies` or something similar)

Comment: According to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41472178/realmlog-native-implementation-not-found you need to call `Realm.init()` **first**, and **then** you need to set the log level.

Comment: @EpicPandaForce Yeah, I realized I had 2 Application constructors called and was setting debug level BEFORE initializing Realm, all works, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the log level like this

```
Realm.init(context);
RealmLog.setLevel(LogLevel.WARN);
```

but you can see other log levels in the [javadoc](https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/api/io/realm/log/LogLevel.html).